# How do I write a decorator and return an authenticated object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, jira

I am writing automation scripts for adding some bugs to Jira via the jira python library.

I have my username and password in a file and I want to make sure that everytime a function is being called (which adds/modifies a bug) is authenticated.

Basically I want to write a decorator.  But this decorator will return a jira object which shall be used by every function.  Below is the function I would write.

```
def return_authed_jira():
    options = {'server': 'https://jira.xxxxyyzzz.com'}
    authed_jira = JIRA(options,  basic_auth=('my_uname', my_passwd))
    return authed_jira
```

Is there a way I can do this using a decorator.  Again, I know I could do it differently without using a decorator, but I want to do this with a decorator.

I have tried writing it myself, but most of the examples that I have seen do not return an object.

This is what I have tried.

```
def authenticate(func):

    def authenticate_and_call(*args, **kwargs):

        options = {'server': 'https://jira.xxxxxxx.com', 'verify': False}
        jira = JIRA(options)
        if not jira.current_user() == 'uname':
            options = {'server': 'https://jira.xxxxxx.com', 'verify': False}
            jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('uname', passwd))
            args.append(jira)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return authenticate_and_call
```

Here I am trying to append the jira object, but that did not work.

This is something that I desire.  Adding the jira object to the args does not make it easy for a function to access.  This is similar to the login decorator where if you try to access a page which needs the user to login, you add the decorator to the function serving the page.

```
@authenticate
def create_new_jira_bug(jira_fields):

    new_issue = jira.create_issue(jira_fields)
    print new_issue.id
```

Below is the new code after `Blckknght` answered the question and made some modifications.

```
def authenticate(func):

    def authenticate_and_call(*args, **kwargs):

        options = {'server': 'https://jira.xyz.com', 'verify': False}
        jira = JIRA(options)
        if not jira.current_user() == 'uname':
            options = {'server': 'https://jira.xyz.com', 'verify': False}
            jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(uname, password))
        return func(*args, jira=jira, **kwargs)
    return authenticate_and_call

@authenticate
def list_projects():

    my_issue = jira.issue('MYKEY-1289')
    print (my_issue.raw.get('fields'))

list_projects()
```

Below is the error I get when I dont add jira to the list_projects function

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/testjira.py", line 44, in <module>
    list_projects()
  File "C:testjira.py", line 33, in authenticate_and_call
    return func(*args, jira=jira, **kwargs)
TypeError: list_projects() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

My question is that I have to pass the jira object to the function before which the decorator is called, otherwise I get this error.  Is there an alternative to this?  It works fine with the below code.  I am trying to get an explanation on why do I have to pass the object when defining the function when I dont have to pass that object when calling the function.

```
@authenticate
def list_projects(jira):

    my_issue = jira.issue('MYKEY-1289')
    print (my_issue.raw.get('fields'))

list_projects()
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Can you add an example of the functions that add/modify a bug?  I imagine they would have to be modified to take an authenticated object as an argument.

Comment: @ronak, I think your remaining confusion is not specific to the authentication issue, but more general about how decorators work. When you're calling `list_projects` in your last code block, you're not actually calling the original function you wrote that takes one argument. Instead you're calling whatever was returned by the decorator (a version of the inner `authenticate_and_call` function it defines). That wrapper function calls the original `list_projects` function with the `jira` argument filled in automatically (the `jira=jira` part of the call to `func`).

Comment: Understood.  How do i get rid of adding jira object to each and every function?  As far as I understand, I already have a default value for jira in the authenticate_and_call function.  Why do I have to explicitly mention it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `append` to `args` because it's a tuple, not a list. To add a value, you'll need to make a new tuple with the value concatenated:

```
args = args + (jira,)
```

Note the comma at the end of `(jira,)`, it's necessary to make it a 1-tuple, rather than a simple parenthesized expression.

You also need to set up the function to be decorated to expect the `jira` argument:

```
@authenticate
def create_new_jira_bug(jira_fields, jira): # expects jira arg from decorator
    new_issue = jira.create_issue(jira_fields)
    print new_issue.id
```

Note that I haven't provided a default value for `jira`. Your current code only adds the `jira` argument to `args` some of the time, which won't work if `jira` is a required argument. It might make more sense to always pass it in from the decorator.

It might be more natural to add a keyword argument to the call made by the decorator, rather than an extra positional argument. This will require all the functions that you're decorating to use the same name for the `jira` object the decorator passes in, but it won't interfere with their handling of other keyword arguments. Adding a positional argument to the end of the existing (as you're currently doing) may break calls using keyword arguments. Here's what the keyword-using decorator might look like:

```
def authenticate(func):
    def authenticate_and_call(*args, **kwargs):
        options = {'server': 'https://jira.xxxxxxx.com', 'verify': False}

        jira = JIRA(options)
        if not jira.current_user() == 'uname':
            jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('uname', passwd))

        return func(*args, jira=jira, **kwargs)

    return authenticate_and_call
```

This will work with the function above, but it won't interfere with a call like:

```
 create_new_jira_bug(jira_fields={"foo": "bar"})
```

Comment: `jira` is the object that is needed to create a new bug.  `jira` object here is the authenticated object.  jira_fields are the items that need to go in the jira issue/bug.  `jira` object is not recognized here `new_issue = jira.create_issue(jira_fields)`

Comment: Oh, I see. Your current code had me a bit confused. You need to add `jira` as a parameter for the function you're decorating, or it cannot possibly get passed in.

Comment: I have like tens of functions which modify issues.  Does that mean that I have to pass the jira object for each and every function.  This is basically what I am trying to avoid.  I could write the below code in all files and get away with passing that
`options = {'server': 'https://jira.xxxxxx.com', 'verify': False}
  authed_jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('uname', passwd))`
and use authed_jira everywhere assuming authed_jira is global, I can use it across files.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some different emphasis on the issues. I'm not sure I understand your comment about using a global. Your decorator seems to be trying to pass a new `jira` object as a parameter, if you have a global variable for it, you don't need to do that.

Comment: This did work upto some extent, but I wanted to see if this could be imporved.  I basically took the same code that you provided for the authenticate decorator.  When I define the function, I have to pass in the `jira` object, for example `@authenticate def get_issue_summary(jira):`  I have to pass in the jira instance.  If I don't add that it gives me a typeerror which says `get_issue_summary() takes no argument (1 given)`

Comment: I think the error is the other way around. You're passing in one argument, but it doesn't expect one, since the `@authenticate` decorator already provides it.